# ng2-page-scroll - overscroll when page is too long

Tags: angular, scroll

Hi in my angular app I use [ng2-page-scroll](https://github.com/Nolanus/ng2-page-scroll).

I have single page with multiple sections:

- [section 1]
- [section 2]
- [section 3]
- etc.

When I scroll sec1 -> sec2 -> sec3 it works as expected, 
but **when I skip sections and scroll sec1 -> sec3  or sec1 -> sec4 etc. there is big overscroll**. The more section I skip the oversrcoll is bigger.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally find the problem: I hade

```
body {
   zoom:95%; 
}
```

in my css